# Set backgroud color of a panel in pairs function call

Tags: r, graphics

The question looks simple, but I don't know how to manage the basic graphic device in R.

I have a code given below and I want to set background color of non-diagonal cells depending on values of correlation coefficient.

```
panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits = 2, cex.cor, ...)
{
  usr <- par("usr"); 
  on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))

  r <- cor(x, y)
  txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
  txt <- paste("r = ", txt, sep = "")

  # try to set background here, but it doesn't affect the output
  if (r > 0.5) 
    par(bg = "red")

  text(0.5, 0.6, txt)

  p <- cor.test(x, y)$p.value
  txt2 <- format(c(p, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
  txt2 <- paste("p = ", txt2, sep = "")
  if (p < 0.01) txt2 <- "p < 0.01"
  text(0.5, 0.4, txt2)
}

pairs(iris[, 1:4], upper.panel = panel.cor)
```

[image: basic output]

The question is how to properly set backgrounds on both upper and bottom panels, but least on the upper panel. Colors can be ranged from red to blue, or they can be discrete: red for r < -0.8, blue for r > 0.8.

Answer (score 3):

To set background colour in `pairs` plot please use the updated code below:

```
# install.packages("RColorBrewer") 
# Needed to get color gradient
library(RColorBrewer)


cols = brewer.pal(11, "RdBu")   # goes from red to white to blue
pal = colorRampPalette(cols)
cor_colors = data.frame(correlation = seq(-1,1,0.01), 
correlation_color = pal(201)[1:201])  # assigns a color for each r correlation value
cor_colors$correlation_color = as.character(cor_colors$correlation_color)

panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits=2, cex.cor)
{
par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
u <- par('usr') 
names(u) <- c("xleft", "xright", "ybottom", "ytop")
r <- cor(x, y,method="spearman",use="complete.obs")
test <- cor.test(x,y)
bgcolor = cor_colors[2+(-r+1)*100,2]    # converts correlation into a specific color
do.call(rect, c(col = bgcolor, as.list(u))) # colors the correlation box

if (test$p.value> 0.05){
text(0.5,0.5,"Insignificant",cex=1.5)
} else{
text(0.5, 0.75, paste("r=",round(r,2)),cex=2.5) # prints correlatoin coefficient
text(.5, .25, paste("p=",formatC(test$p.value, format = "e", digits = 1)),cex=2)  
abline(h = 0.5, lty = 2) # draws a line between correlatoin coefficient and p value
}

}

panel.smooth<-function (x, y, col = "black", bg = NA, pch = 19, cex = 1.2, 
col.smooth = "blue", span = 2/3, iter = 3, ...) {
points(x, y, pch = pch, col = col, bg = bg, cex = cex)
ok <- is.finite(x) & is.finite(y)
if (any(ok)) 
lines(stats::lowess(x[ok], y[ok], f = span, iter = iter), lwd=2.5, col = col.smooth, ...)
}
panel.hist <- function(x, ...)
{
 usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, col="cyan", ...)
}
pairs(iris[1:4],lower.panel=panel.smooth, upper.panel=panel.cor,diag.panel=panel.hist,cex.labels=2)
```

Ouput picture:
[image: correlation matrix with color using pairs()]